# OpenGL ES3 framebuffer generated is completely ignored

Tags: c++, framebuffer, opengl-es-3.0, shadow-mapping

I create a framebuffer object to render scene as depth values to render shadow maps , after the scene initialized and all shaders compiled I add the directional light and create the FBO using this code:

```
            glGenFramebuffers(1, &depthMapFBO);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
            glGenTextures(1, &depthMap);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthMap, 0);
            glDrawBuffers(1, GL_NONE);
            glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
            glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

then in the render loop I render the scene on the generated framebuffer with the depth shader then render the scene again regularly on the screen after unbinding the FBO, this is the code :

```
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, depthMapFBO);
        glViewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        double delta = GetCurrentTime() - firstFrame;
        glm::mat4 lightSpaceProjection = glm::ortho(-10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f);
        glm::mat4 lightSpaceView = glm::lookAt(-sun->direction, glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
        lightSpaceMatrix = lightSpaceProjection * lightSpaceView;
        directDepthShader.use();
        GLuint lsm = glGetUniformLocation(directDepthShader.getProgramID(), "lightSpaceMatrix");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(lsm, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(lightSpaceMatrix));
        for (mesh_it it = phongMeshes.begin(); it != phongMeshes.end(); it++) {
            it->get()->renderDepth(directDepthShader, delta);
        }
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

the first function called before the rendering loop and the FBO generated and has an ID but the problem is the rendering function ignored it although I bind it with its ID which is not minus or even not zero to the extent that if I remove the code which create and adjust the framebuffer nothing changes in the rendering result, I am in that problem for a week !!

Edit:

Vertex shader for depth:

```
#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 4) in ivec4 BoneIDs;
layout (location = 5) in vec4 Weights;

const int MAX_BONES = 100;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform bool skinned;
uniform mat4 gBones[MAX_BONES];
uniform mat4 lightSpaceMatrix;

void main(){
vec4 nPos;
if(skinned){
    mat4 BoneTransform = gBones[BoneIDs[0]] * Weights[0];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[1]] * Weights[1];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[2]] * Weights[2];
    BoneTransform     += gBones[BoneIDs[3]] * Weights[3];
    nPos=BoneTransform * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
else 
    nPos = vec4(position, 1.0);
gl_Position = lightSpaceMatrix * model * nPos;
}
```

the `renderDepth()` for each mesh using the the depth shader program:

```
void Mesh::renderDepth(Shader& shader, double& delta) {
    if (isSkinned) {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgramID(), "skinned"), 1);
        vector<Matrix4f> Transforms;
        BoneTransform(delta, Transforms);
        for (uint j = 0; j < Transforms.size(); j++) {
            Transforms[j] = Transforms[j].Transpose();
            GLuint bonesLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgramID(), (const GLchar*) ("gBones[" + ToString(j) + "]").c_str());
            glUniformMatrix4fv(bonesLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*) Transforms[j]);
        }
    }
    for (uint i = 0; i < m_Entries.size(); i++) {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgramID(), "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(m_Entries[i].matrix));
        glBindVertexArray(m_Entries[i].m_VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_Entries[i].NumIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: no I will do now

Comment: i checked the framebuffer with `if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
     LOGI("framebuffer incomplete");
    }` and it is complete, in OpenGL ES3 which I use doesn't has  `glDrawBuffer` it has only `glDrawBuffers`

Comment: I did, unfortunately still black, I added the vertex depth shader and the render function for each mesh to the question if it may clear anything

Comment: I found the solution in this Page https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Common_Mistakes it was a Depth Buffer Precision so I used the internal format GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 and the type GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT and the surprise it worked, I can't thank you @Rabbid76 well all your comments helped me and made me understand more, Thank you